# migrating contents to UIScrollView in xcode iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiscrollview

I am a beginner and I am a bit confused about `UIScrollView`.
Here is my case.

Without `UIScrollView`, I added and made stuffs on `UIViewController`.

Later on, I realized I have to implement `UIScrollView`, and now I have to **migrate** all my contents to inside of the `UIScrollView`.

If I drag out `UIScrollView` from storyboard and move all my elements into that `UIScrollView`,

I am guessing the order of contents would be:

**from**: `UIViewController -> IBOutlets`

**to**: `UIViewController -> UIScrollView -> IBOutlets`

Thus, do I have to change the way I access `IBOutlets` on my `UIViewController`?

Will this be the correct way?

**before**:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *coursenameLabel;
```

**and access:**

```
_coursenameLabel.text = @"text";
```

**after**:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *coursenameLabel;
```

**and access like this?**

```
_scrollView.coursenameLabel.text = @"text";
```

Would this be the simplest way to move all my contents to inside of `UIScrollView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Th simplest way is to select all the UI elements you want to move, and choose embed in scroll view from the editor menu. you do not have to change the way you access the outlets; the outlets still belong to the controller, not the scroll view. You will lose any constraints you made to your views that you move; you will have to remake them all.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not the correct way to access them.

Your property coursenameLabel will be accessed the same way as before self.coursenameLabel (_coursenameLabel) as they are still properties on your UIViewController.

Edit: @rdelmar answer is easier. Select all your views and embed in Scroll View.

#### Before:

[image: Storyboards with some views]

#### Mid:

[image: Editor -> Embed In -> Scroll View]

#### After:

[image]

<strike>The simplest way to migrate your views would be to use the hierarchy view in storyboards. (Screenshots to come soon)</strike>